# how to get the first quoted text inside a sentence

Tags: javascript, string

Suppose I have a sentence and it has 2 quoted texts.
Example:

> My Name 'is xyz' and I work 'on servicenow'.

I want to get only "is xyz" not "on servicenow".
It will be very helpful if any one tell me how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`'My Name "is xyz" and I work "on servicenow".'.split('"')[1]`

Comment: thanks a lot. it solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Use `split` function

```js
alert('My Name "is xyz" and I work "on servicenow".'.split('"')[1]);
```